# select few rows from resultset mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

i have used a select command in my java program and stored its value in the result set. now while looping in the resultset i want to use a select command which will select the first 5 lines of the resultset and insert into other table. for the second time, it should select the next 5 lines and insert into the table. and for the third time, so on..

```
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
s.executeQuery("Select * from table1");
ResultSet res = s.getResultSet();
while(res.next()){
 // here i want to select the first 5 lines of the result set and insert in the second       table
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing your query using `LIMIT` and using a PreparedStatement. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT ?,?
```

This has a couple of advantages:

- You are not fetching everything in one shot - can be sometimes a performance benefit if you've a lot many rows to deal with in your table
- You can change pre-define the number of elements that you want to fetch in every single batch

So your code will look something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
final int FETCH_LIMIT   = 5; //number of elements to fetch per batch
final int BATCH_LIMIT   = 3; //number of batches you would want

int currentRows = 0;
try{
    ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT ?,?");
    for(int currentBatch = 0; currentBatch < BATCH_LIMIT; currentBatch++){
        ps.clearParameters();
        ps.setInt(1, currentRows);
        ps.setInt(2, currentRows + FETCH_LIMIT);

        try{
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                // do your work
            }
        }catch(Exception exe){
            //manage exception
        }finally{
            //manage resultset
        }
        currentRows += FETCH_LIMIT;
    }
}catch(Exception exe){
    //Handle your exception
}
finally{
    //Manage your resources
}
```

Comment: @sunleo - The question was tagged with `MySQL` and hence the suggestion. But, yes I agree LIMIT is not supported in all RDBMS, although most of them have some kind of functionality to set the fetch limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
s.executeQuery("Select * from table1");
ResultSet res = s.getResultSet();

while(res.next()){
    // here i want to select the first 5 lines of the result set and insert in the second       table
    while(res.next() && (res.getRow()%5) !=0){
        //select from this table
        //call insert method(what selected)
    }
}
```

Comment: this will select the 5 lines and will insert to other table, now for the next time will it select the next 5 lines..???\

Comment: @Nikki : yes why not?you are inserting res object getRow() is just giving you the row number. I'm not manipulating the traversal of res object

Comment: @BhavikShah it will select next 5 next 5 and .. it won't stop after first 5 am I right ?

Comment: @BhavikShah so in the second select command i have to select * from table 1 ?

Comment: @BhavikShah hi, i tried your code, bt its selecting the alternate rows, like, row 2,4,6 and so on.....

Answer (score 0):

Please add a falg and use that is it

```
int i=0;

while(res.next() && i< 5){
//select from this table
//call insert method(what selected)
i++;
}
```

Comment: this is a plausible solution but it not very neat! in my opinion

Comment: @BhavikShah Please let me know what you mean by neat solution ?

Comment: neat solution means avoiding the use of unnecessary variable like 'i' in your case.

Comment: do you think without passing that "i", you can get 5 values exactly.If you can please let me know I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create another insert query dynamically inside the while loop and execute it outside the while loop